# Why does this 'sed' fail inside qx() in Perl?

Tags: perl, sed

This sed works, to replace the value for Java home in a shell script:

`sed -i 's#^JAVA_HOME=.*$#JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle.x86_64"#' /apps/tempbsu.sh`

but now I am trying to use/invoke that `sed` from inside a Perl app, using `qx()`:

`qx(sed -i 's#^JAVA_HOME=.*$#JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle.x86_64"#' /apps/tempbsu.sh);`

and when I do that, I am getting an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unterminated `s' command

From checking, I gather that error is happening because the sed is missing the last delimiter, but it seems like it is correct, i.e.:

```
sed -i 's#.....#.......#' /apps/tempbssu.sh
```

Can someone tell me why this `sed` is failing with I use in a `qx()` in Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$#JAVA_HOME` is treated as a Perl variable (the number of the last element of the array variable). Escape it: `\$#JAVA_HOME`

Comment: But note - `use strict;` and `use warnings` will tell you about this problem (unless you for some reason declare `@JAVA_HOME`)